# Help with installing apache2 and PHP (silly question)

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I need to install wordpress, so I'm installing LAMP Stack with PhpMyAdmin following [this TecMint step-by-step](https://www.tecmint.com/install-lamp-with-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-20-04/)

It was working just fine until step 12:

12. Next, test if Apache is working in conjunction with PHP. Create an info.php page under the web document root `/var/www/html/` directory as shown.

```
$ sudo vi /var/www/html/info.php
```

Copy and paste the following code in the file, then save the file and exit it.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

I have no idea of how to do that "copy and paste" and then "save the file and exit" from the terminal.

Please help!!

Comment: Hello. Try man vi I assume you know how to cut and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re going to use `vi`, then this is how you do it:

1. Open the file for editing:

   ```
   sudo vi /var/www/html/info.php
   ```
2. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to **I**nsert text
3. Paste the contents. If this is via SSH, it may be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (depending on your client).
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to **Esc**ape editing mode
5. Press <kbd>:</kbd> to issue commands
6. Press <kbd>W</kbd> to **W**rite the changes
7. Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to **Q**uit `vi`

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked!!!!